# Printing output in new line in java I/O files

Tags: java, file-io

i want to print the output in new line how to do this? 
Below is the output.

```
CHILD: Child line one oneCHILD: Child line one twoCHILD: Child line one three
CHILD: Child line two oneCHILD: Child line two twoCHILD: Child line two three
```

here is my code for it...

```
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileWriterChild = new FileWriter(outputFileForChild);
        brChild = new BufferedWriter(fileWriterChild);
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int child_line_no = 0;

        int buffer = 0;
        String currentLine = br.readLine();
        while (currentLine != null) {

            if (currentLine.contains("CHILD:")) {

                Files.write(Paths.get("C:/output.child.txt"),
                        currentLine.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

            }
            currentLine = br.readLine();

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {

        fis.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: when you have finally wrote the line in file add bufferedWriter.newLine();... it will write the nest output in new line

Comment: I suggest you first clean up your code and decide on how you want to access the files; either via FileInputStream and BufferedReader and FileOutputStream and BufferedWriter *or* via FileReader *or* via Files.write(...) &c. As it is now, you're opening 2 files for reading and 1 for writing, and then you open the output file again each time with `Files.write(...)`. Doesn't really make much sense this way.

Comment: @CoderNeji: its giving the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method newLine() from the type BufferedWriter... And where to add your code can u merge ur code in my code and post it here

Comment: @sindhupandey you have to make an object of the bufferedwriter.class and use it for file writing.... See my previous comment once again... it's called by an object... not by class...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what do you want to do. Here are my two ways:

**Appending one line to the end of file**

```
void WriteLog(String date, String message) {
    String logFileName = <path to file>;
    File logFile = new File(logFileName);
    //make directories
    logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(logFile, true)) {
        writer.write(message);
        writer.write("\r\n");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Cls_log.LogError("Error writing log - " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

**Writing all strings as lines to file (overwriting file)**

```
public static void WriteABcardLog(Map<String,String> etiquetteCache) {
    File logFile = new File(<path to file>);
    logFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(logFile)) {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = etiquetteCache.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
            try {
                writer.print(entry.getKey() + ";" + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Cls_log.LogError(e);
            }
        }
        writer.println();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Cls_log.LogError("Error writing etiquette log - " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```